# Python numpy stack rows into a single column

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I am working on a data frame like the following and want to reshape them into a single column and create another column using the original index:

[image]

convert the above data frame by stacking each row (indexed by "year") into a single column (named "value") and create another column filled with these values' corresponding "year" to generate a new data frame with two columns (value, year) like the following

[image]

How can I quickly achieve this using any of the numpy commands?

Thank you.

Comment: You could start with something like [rot90](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html) which would give you your values axis down the side. You could then slice off the year row and then assign those values back, since they'll occur every 50 lines it should be easy to orchestrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just came to me that I can do this rather quickly with the following code

```js
df['year'] = df.index
stacked = df.set_index('year').stack()
df = stacked.reset_index(name='value')
df.drop('level_1', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

This should do the trick. I should have gave it more thought before lodging this question, sorry.